# IntelliJ won't compile basic JavaFX program copied from documentation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm making my first GUI program using Scene Builder and Java FX in IntelliJ. I wanted to make a choice box so I looked at the Java documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html

I based my choicebox off the documentation and found that IntelliJ didn't recognize the method. So I then just straight up copy pasted from the documentation and still got an error. My code is as follows:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;

public class Controller {
 ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
 cb.getItems().addAll("item1", "item2", "item3");
}
```

The ".getItems()" is in red text and the error "cannot resolve symbol getItems" is the error listed. Someone else compiled the program and it worked for their machine.

Answer (score 3):

```
cb.getItems().addAll("item1", "item2", "item3");
```

needs to be put inside of a method.

The correct code is:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;

public class Controller {
    @FXML private ChoiceBox cb;

    public void initialize() {
        cb.getItems().addAll("item1", "item2", "item3");
    }
}
```

the `initialize` method will be called by the `FXMLLoader` after injecting the fields.

---

Edit: Added @fabian's comments on the `FXML` loading/initialization

Comment: Cool. Now I just have to get this to actually work. It compiles now but no choices are shown when clicking on the choicebox. The ID's match up and all of that. I am going to guess I need to do some other method to populate the choices or something??

Comment: @user2778506: You need to keep `cb` as a field and annotate it with `@FXML`: `@FXML private ChoiceBox cb;`, but do not initialize it (the `FXMLLoader` does this). You can find examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers#t=201607272009269385103, just look for the `fx:id` attribute in the fxml and the corresponding fields in the controllers...

Comment: @fabian thanks for taking care of the `JavaFX` stuff, I've never really used the platform before :)

Comment: Did all of that. Take a look at the webm:

Comment: @user2778506 Can you post your code in your question, instead of a video. I couldn't see anywhere that you had set the controller class in the fxml file, for example. As for tutorials, a lot of people seem to like [this one](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/).

Comment: Ahahah you're a smart guy. I feel dumb. It seems that when you delete everything in Scene Builder it resets the Controller class to a null value. Now I know, and everything works. Thanks.